# Flask: multi field POST request

Tags: python, flask

This is a route for a page to edit general info about a game in a database

each game has the following fields :

1. game_name
2. game_year
3. game_dev
4. game_OS
5. game_CPU
6. game_RAM
7. game_GPU

```
@webui.route('/edit/<id>' , methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit_game(id ):
    handle = Game.query.get(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in request.form:
            if not request.form[item]:
                print (item + " was not changed ")  
            else:
                # handle.info = request.form['info']

                pass
```

Can you enumerate over handle values and check the output over `request.form[item]`

Is there a way to edit the values of the selected game other than this

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        
        if  request.form['game_name']:
            handle.name = request.form['game_name']

        if  request.form['game_year']:
            handle.year = request.form['game_year']

        if  request.form['game_dev']:
            handle.dev = request.form['game_dev']

        if  request.form['game_OS']:
            handle.OS = request.form['game_OS']

        if  request.form['game_CPU']:
            handle.CPU = request.form['game_CPU']

        if  request.form['game_RAM']:
            handle.RAM = request.form['game_RAM']

        if  request.form['game_GPU']:
            handle.GPU = request.form['game_GPU']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enumerate the submitted form fields:

```
for key in request.form.keys():
    print(f"key: {key} => value: {request.form[key]}")
```